# Capture a line containing a "." or ":" but not ending with a period

Tags: php, regex, character-encoding

I'm trying to create a regex containing character set which can contain a period or colon but may not end with a period. So I want to mach a line saying `"Lorem./: Ipsom dolor sit"` but not `"Lorem ipsum dolor sit."`

This is what my current regex looks like, but it's not working as it will match if the string ends on a period or colon:

`/(\n{2,})([ \wåäöÅÄÖ,()%+\-:.]{2,75}[^.:])(\n{1,})/`

I'm looking for headings in a huge, badly formatted plain text file. And the general pattern in this file is that a heading is always preceded by two newlines or more and always succeeded by one newline or more. Also a heading sometimes ends on a `:` but never on a `.` however they sometimes contain a `.` or `:`. Also they're always 2-75 characters long and never preceded by another heading.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I realised that my explanation where quite bad and partly wrong thus updated this post.

Comment: I don't really understand your regex as it is now. You want to match 2 or more newlines, followed by 2-75 of your "allowed characters", followed by any character except dot or colon, followed by one or more newlines, followed by one "allowed character" except dot or colon?

Comment: What I want match is 2 or more newlines followed by 2-75 allowed characters (not ending with . or : even tho they are allowed) followed by one or more newlines. The last bit were a mistake in my copy an pasting.

Comment: Aha - thanks for clarifying. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, if you want to match a string not ending in a dot, just add `(?<!\.)$` to the end of the regex.

This is a [negative lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

In your special case, the match is supposed to continue after this, though, so we need a different approach:

```
/\n{2,}([ \wåäöÅÄÖ,()%+\-:.]{2,75}(?<!\.))\n+/
```

will match any line that

- follows two or more newlines (`\n{2,}`),
- consists only of 2 to 75 allowed characters (`[ \wåäöÅÄÖ,()%+\-:.]`),
- doesn't end in `.` (`(?<!\.)` - )
- and is followed by at least one newline (`\n+`).

**EDIT:**

A new, expanded regex, trying to incorporate some of the logic discussed in the comments below; formatted as a verbose regex:

```
preg_match_all(
    '/(?<=\n\n)   # Assert that there are two newlines before the current position
    ^             # Assert that we\'re at the start of a line
    (?![\d -]+$)  # Assert that the line consists not solely of digits, spaces and -s
                  # Assert that the line doesn\'t consist of two Uppercase Words
    (?!\s*\p{Lu}\p{L}*\s+\p{Lu}\p{L}*\s*$)
                  # Match 2-75 of the allowed characters
    [ \wåäöÅÄÖ,()%+\-:.]{2,75}
    (?<!\.)       # Assert that the last one isn\'t a dot
    $             # Assert position at the end of a line
    (?=\n)        # Assert that one newline follows.
    /mxu', 
    $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

Comment: Well done! Isn’t it nice when some of these turn out to be quick and easy? :)

Comment: I don't really understand how this works. I tried just adding it to my regex to see the result however it resulted in no matches so I tried removing the $ as I'm trying to match the pattern several times within a very long string but that had no effect as it still matched "\n\nBla bla bla.\n".

Comment: My first post weren't so explaining very well so I updated it. Look at my explanation now and I hope that you'll understand what I mean. However thanks for the help so far.

Comment: That works rather well I just have the problem that sometimes a name or phone number is preceded by two newlines and succeeded by a newline. Got any tip on how to handle these cases?

Comment: How would you describe the difference between an entry you do want to match and one of these entries? I. e., how can *you*  tell you don't want that entry - so we can tell the regex how to differentiate between the two?

Comment: Well that's what I'm thinking. I mean a heading can be two words of the same length as a first name followed by a last name, you could probably detect a phone number as it's always 8-13 numbers but they may be grouped with spaces or dashes between the groups. However then name one seems hard.

Comment: There's often contact information at the end of one of the plaintext documents however not always. This contact information is spaced in a way so that the name and sometimes other parts of the contact information is regarded as headings by the regex. I accepted your answer as it solves my initial question even if that regex by itself doesn't quite work out in my situation.

Comment: I just realised that what differs a name from a heading even if the heading contains 2 words. In a heading the second word would most likely start with a small letter however if the second word in a 2 word heading starts with a capital it's likely that it's actually a name.

Comment: OK, new try - how about this? And @tchrist: Quick and easy? not really :)

Comment: That new version looks awesome however I'm using preg_replace so I guess I can just omit the PREG_PATTERN_ORDER parameter. I'm going to test with this new regex and post back results.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker I tried the new regex and it does not take names anymore however it does not accept a heading if it's the first line in the file, earlier I modified it to (\n{2,}|^) but that won't work now, because of the m flag? Also I had to add a capture group around the actual match for the replace. Another problem I saw is that they sometimes write Phone: 230 092 132, Nr: 3223, etc. Also sometimes the corporation name is seen as a heading in the contact info. Thanks a lot for helping me I've learnt a lot about regex from this. Could you explain the row with {Lu} I don't quite understand it

Comment: Also if it's the last line in the file I can assume it's not a heading. Thanks for bearing with me, you are a truly helpful and nice person.

Comment: @Hultner: Try `(?<=\n\n|\A)` to catch titles at the start of the string. With these other unwanted matches, you're rapidly moving out of what can reasonably done with a (single) regex. Perhaps you need to do a quick "first pass" and then refine the results?. `\p{Lu}` is a shorthand for an uppercase letter, `\p{L}` is just any letter. Both work with Unicode characters, so also accented characters will be matched.

Comment: `\p{L}` matches any character that meets the Unicode definition of a letter, and `\p{Lu}` matches only *uppercase* letters.  I believe you have to add the `u` modifier to use those things, and make sure both the regex and the source text are in UTF-8.

Comment: Yeah I found out about \p*, \A and \Z when I were researching to evolve my regex more and managed to fix so that it won't use think the last line is a heading and so that it would match on the first heading of the file. I also managed to fid the Phone:, Nr: problem basing on the same principle as the name exception however I'm now working in a exception where they write Location followed by date in Swedish but not getting it to work. This is what I've got so far `(?!\s*\p{L}+\s+[Dd]en\s+[1-3][0-9]\s+\p{L}{3,9}\s+[0-9]{4}$)` but doesn't match `Malmö den 14 februari 2011`. I've learnt a lot.

Comment: This should match, unless there is whitespace after `2011`.

Comment: Woah what a stupid rookie mistake. Yes there were a white space after 2011. Thanks again.

Comment: By the way, I guess you'd really love [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com). I learned nearly everything I know about regexes by using this tool.

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out. I've heard about it sometime before but never really tried it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the expression in `^EXPRESSION$`. This will mean that you need the expression to match the entire line. As written the expression can just ignore the last character if it is a period or colon.

Answer (score 0):

Updated in respect to the changed question:

```
/(^|[\n\r]{3,}).{2,75}(?<!\.)[\n\r]+/
```

[Example](http://regexr.com?2t3io) with possible text etc..

(I'm looking for either `\n` or `\r` because the editor on that page seems to treat newlines as `\r`s)

#### Previous answer:

```
/^.+[^.:\n\r]$/m
```

[Example](http://regexr.com?2t3if).

Comment: Do you have the `/m` because you expect to match in the middle of a multiline string?  If so, why do you include `\n` and `\r` in the bracketed character class?

Comment: I have the `m` flag, because I understood it the way, that there is a multiline string with multiple lines/possible matches. And I included the line breaks, because somehow a following empty line was matching the line before incorrectly (try via the link).

Comment: Yeah well as I'm looking for headings in a huge badly formatted plaintext file. And the general pattern in this file is that a heading is always preceded by two newlines or more and always succeeded by one newline or more. Also a heading sometimes ends on a : but never on a . (that made me relise I made a mistake) however the sometimes contain a . or :. Also there always 2-75 characters long and never preceded by another heading.

Comment: @Hultner: Updated my question. See also the example, as I put a text there that might be in a similar format as yours.

Comment: I thank you for your answer but the one by Tim is better in my situation. But your updated regex is very close to his regex however a wildcard is a bit to unspecific as it sometimes chose list items as headings as well (which they are not) and such. The version provided by Tim already matches to much. And I won't need \r since the plaintext files always use \n. If you want a test which do not use flash regex try http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/pregtest.htm. It not quite as flashy (no pun intended) but it produces the actual php results.